# how to verify digital signature with public key - python

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, md5, public-key

i'm trying to verfy signature of file and i was given a message.txt(data) and message.txt.sign(which i assume that is the signature) i also given the public key(publickey.pem) now i wrote a code in python using pycharm and inspired by this code:

```
def verify_sign(public_key_loc, signature, data):
    '''
    Verifies with a public key from whom the data came that it was indeed 
    signed by their private key
    param: public_key_loc Path to public key
    param: signature String signature to be verified
    return: Boolean. True if the signature is valid; False otherwise. 
    '''
    from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA 
    from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5 
    from Crypto.Hash import SHA256 
    from base64 import b64decode 
    pub_key = open(public_key_loc, "r").read() 
    rsakey = RSA.importKey(pub_key) 
    signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(rsakey) 
    digest = SHA256.new() 
    # Assumes the data is base64 encoded to begin with
    digest.update(b64decode(data)) 
    if signer.verify(digest, b64decode(signature)):
        return True
    return False
```

it dosent work for me  , any help please?!

Comment: openssl dgst -md5 -verify ./public.pem -signature ./message_enc_sign ./message_rsa
this is the command to do it in openssl but i want the python suitable solotion please